# Express-validator: Define accepted fields

Tags: express-validator

i am using the express-validator npm package. I looking for a way to prevent the user to send undesired fields on the body.

So, i want a validator that defines the accepted fields on the body. How can I do this with express-validator?

Answer (score 0):

Just use matchedData from the filter API.

https://express-validator.github.io/docs/filter-api.html

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading that it is a good idea to achieve this by taking a whitelist approach in the handler function. So, don't just incorporate all the posted variables. Specifically create a variable for each posted value you are expecting. Then If data is posted which you are not expecting it will not be incorporated into your program. Now I have written this I can see it is pretty much the same as the first answer.